# How to pass Repository name for GIT using C#

Tags: c#, git

I developing a program to push files to remote repo of BonoBo GIT.
I have below code

```
using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/your/repo"))
    {
        LibGit2Sharp.PushOptions options = new LibGit2Sharp.PushOptions();
        options.CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler(
            (url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
                {
                    Username = USERNAME,
                    Password = PASSWORD
                });
        repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches[BRANCHNAME], options);
    }
    `
```

I have remote repo URL:'http://localhost/Bonobo.git.server/secondRepo.git'. where should I put this url? if I put this in the place of "url" in the code I am getting error as 'Method name expected'

Comment: Litterally where it says "path/to/your/repo", maybe ? Also this isn't your code, right ?

Comment: Actually where it says  "path/to/your/repo" it will be local repository path (for.e.g - D:\tkE\MyRepo).  The issue that we are facing is that in the Constructor CredentialsHandler, we are not sure what is the datatype of url, usernameFromUrl, types. Can you please let me know how to get the data types

Comment: Quickly looking at the github (you should add that to your question, the lib that you are using) this is what i get as for `CredentialHandler` 's constructor parameters type: `public delegate Credentials CredentialsHandler(string url, string usernameFromUrl, SupportedCredentialTypes types);`

Comment: Also, i don't want to be rude, but are you sure about "repo"'s utility ? if it's a local repository it kinda feels weird that it's doing a Network.Push on it right after that :/ (could be 100% wrong, it just feels weird to me that's all)

Comment: The library that we are using is libgit2sharp. Actually our main goal is that we want to write a utility class to push, pull files in Bonobo Git server.  So in the utility class we are writing method that will accept the local file and then push it to Git and also vice versa - get the branch updates from Git Repo and pull and update on the local directory